# How to make single admin to access single store products only

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.6

In magento I am having 3 websites and it contains 6 to 7 store views. I want as a single admin has to access single store products only. He should not modify the products in another stores. How can I do this?

I have read in magneto documentation as to create new admin in system/permissions/roles and modify there. But trying with this, the new admin is restricted to only creating of products or for dashboard or for shippings or for tax module only. But I need like the new admin has to be accessed to only one store only..

So how can I do this??

Comment: Modules may be a solution? http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?id=&s=7&pl=0&eb=0&hp=0&q=admin+permission+store&t=0&p=1

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a little late reply but anyone who is interested, answer from mprototype is perfectly valid as long as you/your client uses a Magento Enterprise edition. Checked in versions 1.12 and above.

Answer (score 1):

When you goto :

System -> Permissions -> Roles

While defining the role you can choose custom scope and checkbox the stores you want then to have access to.

Comment: I cant see any checkbox with stores function. I can see only manage Thanks for ur quick reply. There I can see manage store option only, But this not my requirement. I need as in the manage products tab, there will be choose stores. There he has to be see only his store name. Nt all the other stores. Let me know if I am missing any thing..

Comment: Exactly what I said before fits the requirement, first you must create a user role limited to the store view and limited to the products administration module.

Comment: This answers pretty vague... any chance for some more specific instructions? I don't see checkboxes for stores either.

Comment: Or maybe... is this an Enterprise Edition feature only? Or is it available in Magento Community Edition?

Comment: You can choose a custom scope only in Magento EE. Otherwise, you must install a module like the one written above. That's why your answer didn't fit here, as @PavanKumar wants the answer for CE (indirectly, if you read the tags he wrote).

Comment: Modules may be a solution? http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?id=&s=7&pl=0&eb=0&hp=0&q=admin+permission+store&t=0&p=1

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I am late but any of these will do what you are looking for.  In fact, it will provide even more flexibility.

http://www.aitoc.com/en/magentomods_advanced_permissions.html
http://amasty.com/magento-advanced-permissions.html

Happy Coding !!!

Comment: it is not free though